# Can you install/use Travis Cli inside travis script?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

As a part of my my customized travis build I would like to use [Travis command-line client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#the-travis-client-) inside `after_success` script. I need that to trigger some operations on other travis jobs (other repositories) after each successfull build in this particular repo. So two questions:

- Is it possible at all?
- If so is there any smart or quick way to do that?

As far as I know Travis Cli has several ruby dependencies that may not be available by default. But perhaps it is by default installed on travis VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible. However, this would only work for `language: ruby` jobs.

For your specific case, you can do:

```
after_success:
  # install travis cli
  - gem install --no-document travis
  # setup travis shell autocomplete
  - echo "y" | travis --version
  # do travis cli stuff
  - travis do stuff
```

If you have a project using another language, then this becomes much more complicated.

Comment: Does "much more complicated" mean you can't call gem in project that is not using ruby? I will have to test it.

Comment: Actually I tested using gem and installing travis  in 'after_success' stage on **python** build and (at least on enterprise travis ci) it seems to works perfectly.